# Why formly-field doesn't render the component?

Tags: angular, angular-formly, ngx-formly

I made input component and render component in formly.

This is simple thing: the app component is render the render-component and render-component is render the input component.

But the input component is not rendered. why how make it works?

I followed according to [formly repeat example](https://formly.dev/examples/advanced/repeating-section).

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/black-wind-p0erg?file=/src/app/input.component.ts:89-212)

```
@Component({
  selector: "formly-input",
  template: ` <input /> `
})
export class InputTypeComponent extends FieldType {}
```

Render component:

```
@Component({
  selector: "formly-render",
  template: `
    this should be render:
    <formly-field [field]="{ type: 'input' }"></formly-field>
  `
})
export class RenderTypeComponent extends FieldType {}
```

Both register in the root component:

```
  FormlyModule.forRoot({
      types: [
        { name: "input", component: InputTypeComponent },
        { name: "formly-render", component: RenderTypeComponent }
      ]
    })
```